# authority distribution and hub distribution

Tags: graph-theory, terminology

I want to understand the concepts authority distribution and hub distribution. As I see in gephi software, Authority measures how valuable information stored at that node is. Hub measure the quality of the nodes links. Is there any standard definition for these concepts?(more mathematical def)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Probably you are looking for this:

J. Kleinberg. Authoritative sources in a hyperlinked environment. Proc. 9th ACM-SIAM Symposium on Discrete Algorithms, 1998. Extended version in Journal of the ACM 46(1999)

http://www.cs.cornell.edu/home/kleinber/auth.pdf